Adding a WIFI timer switch to high/low/off switch for a whole house fan
I'd like to put a WIFI timer on a whole house fan switch which has a high, low and off setting. Once the whole house fan is turned to either low or high setting, I'd like to be able to activate it or turn it off remotely. If I wire the hot lead to the timer and run the load lead from the timer to both the high and low terminals on the fan switch, will that work? (The neutral wire will be connected to the timer and bypass the house fan switch. I know the windows need to be open and the timer needs to handle 1/3 hp.)
If there is a more elegant solution that would also allow me to change from high to low fan setting remotely, please let me know. Wiring diagrams would be appreciated.

Run power first to the timer. Then to the input of the switch.


If I wire the hot lead to the timer and run the load lead from the timer to both the high and low terminals on the fan switch, will that work?

If by "work" you mean kill the fan motor by applying power to two terminals at the same time that should NEVER be energized at the same time, sure. Watch the magic smoke pour forth.
Timer output to fan switch input, where it gets "always hot" now, let the fan switch pick the speed, or learn to think about what you are doing before trying to come up with ways to ignite things by not thinking and playing with electricity.
